# Add an "Owner" input field in VF page to update record owner

Tags: apex, visualforce

The use case I'm working on dictates me to build a solution that'd work in Classic.

The goal is to create a quick action on the Case Feed. The quick action then will call a Visualforce page to display certain input field which upon submission will create an Opportunity record. The ask is to also include the "Owner" field in the VF page for users to select the owner for the opportunity that will be created.

However, the only owner input field I can technically use is:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!Case.OwnerID}" label="Owner"/>
```

Using this, I can only update the Case Owner and not Opportunity owner per requirement. Is there any suggested alternative on how to add the "Owner" field in the VF page that would allow users to select the owner for Opportunity record?

Edit: Going with a workaround route of redirecting the page to Opportunity detail page from where the owner can be changed. Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: Is the Owner going to be dynamic or is it going to be a static owner? I believe you can utilize process builder for a portion of this but depending on this will depend on how complex it would get.

Comment: This seems achievable by just introducing another field say on your VF and be able to utilize that in your code logic. Because you have a custom VF, you have the full control here to manipulate the input per your needs. What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you @JayantDas for taking the time out to format the post and posting a response! Conceptually on the same page as you that creating a brand new lookup field that will list out all the users and queues for selection is certainly possible. However, since architecturally speaking, the query to read and show all the users and queues in form of lookup in VF is high effort/low value, I was looking for any alternatives like  <apex:inputfield value="{!Case.OwnerID}" label="Owner"/>. As a workaround, I'd simply redirect the users to Opportunity detail page where they can change owner there ;)